# NUnit, TestDriven.NET, WatiN and Specflow

Tags: c#, nunit, watin, specflow

I am trying to do some BDD testing using Specflow, NUnit and WatiN. I am using TestDriven.NEt to run the test. Here is my first test:

```
[Binding]
    [TestFixture, RequiresSTA]
    public class RegisterUserSteps
    {
        private IE _ie = new IE();

        [When(@"the user visits the registration page")]
        public void WhenTheUserVisitsTheRegistrationPage()
        {
            _ie.GoTo("http://localhost:1064/Register/"); 
        }


        [When(@"enter the following information")]
        public void WhenEnterTheFollowingInformation(Table table)
        {
            foreach(var tableRow in table.Rows)
            {
                var field = _ie.TextField(Find.ByName(tableRow["Field"])); 

                if(!field.Exists)
                {
                    Assert.Fail("Field does not exists!");
                }

                field.TypeText(tableRow["Value"]);
            }
        }

        [When(@"click the ""Register"" button")]
        public void WhenClickTheRegisterButton()
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
        }

        [Then(@"the user should be registered")]
        public void ThenTheUserShouldBeRegistered()
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
        }

    }
```

The problem is that it never goes to the

```
 [When(@"enter the following information")]
            public void WhenEnterTheFollowingInformation(Table table)
```

It just launches the browser and perform the first step. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you post the actual feature text?

Answer (score 2):

Without looking at the test, it seems you are missing an important step (Given). Usually it is like this:

```
Given I go to some page
And all the set up data are available - optional
When I enter the following info
And I click "Register" button
Then I see something
```

Basically the steps are GWT (Given, When, Then). It's Gherkin language, so if you google for it you'll see more info. When you have multiple things for a given step, you have to use `And`, example, `When ...... And.......`, not `When...... When........`

Comment: To add to this, it doesn't seem like you should be doing any assserts except in the Then conditions.  Givens do things to setup (which may not do anything in the browser), when should be the user actions, and thens the asserts.  At least we've been having a lot of success doing that.

Comment: This is true but important to note is that none of the Gherkin keywords are required, nor is their order important from a TECHNICAL standpoint. BUT from a semantic and readability standpoint I fully agree